# CUDA x64 + openCV 2.1

Tags: opencv, cuda

the previous tutorials have not shown anybody else having this problem: compiling openCV and CUDA projects in vs2008 in windows 7 x64.  but i have been stuck on it for over a week.

Zero problems building openCV samples and my own code and CUDA within their own projects.  I cannot get them to build in a single project together no matter what i try to do in VS.

Comment: What does the compiler message says ? is openCV compiled in 64 bit?
are the cuda libs also in 64 bit?

Comment: Indeed both libraries must be compiled as 64bit for your application to work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good guide, i'm sure it will help you: [How to Build OpenCV 2.2 with GPU (CUDA) on Windows 7](http://blog.cuvilib.com/2011/03/22/how-to-build-opencv-2-2-with-gpu-cuda-on-windows-7/)

Answer (score 0):

self solve

this is NOT possible in windows, don't bother trying... i have since changed to ubuntu with no problems

Answer (score 0):

It is possible when compiling OpenCV in x64 mode with checking "With Cuda" in CMAKE. Also you need to have the x64 Cuda Toolkit with Nvidia Performance Primitives and GPU Computing SDK.

Comment: the problem is that openCV does not support x64 in windows.